# Equivalence between function templates and abbreviated function templates

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++20

<sub>*All standard references below refers to the [current ISO Standard Working Draft](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/), generated on 2020-06-22.*</sub>

---

[[dcl.fct]/18](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.fct#18) states that [extract, **emphasis** mine]:

> An *abbreviated function template* is a function declaration that has one or more generic parameter type placeholders ([dcl.spec.auto]). **An abbreviated function template is equivalent to a function template** ([temp.fct]) whose *template-parameter-list* includes one invented type *template-parameter* for each generic parameter type placeholder of the function declaration, **in order of appearance.** [...]

Such that the following to function declarations are areuably *equivalent*:

```
template <typename T>
void f(T);

void f(auto);  // re-declaration
```

We may note, however, that the example of [[dcl.fct]/18](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.fct#18.sentence-8) states that

> [...]
>
> These declarations are **functionally equivalent** (**but not equivalent**) to the following declarations.
>
> [...]

which may arguably (I'm unsure how interpret this) conflict with the equivalence statement in the prior passage.

Now, both GCC 10.1.0 and Clang 10.0.0 (as well as GCC:HEAD and Clang:HEAD) have some mixed behavior here. If we declare a function template and later define it (/re-declare it) using a mixed classical function template syntax with abbreviated function template syntax, Clang accepts most cases (defining a previously declared function) whereas GCC rejects all (sees the (attempted) re-declarations as separately declared functions with subsequent ambiguity failures in overload resolution):

```
// A1: Clang OK, GCC error
template <typename T>
void a(T);

void a(auto) {}

// B1: Clang OK, GCC error
void b(auto);

template <typename T>
void b(T) {}

// C1: Clang OK, GCC error
template <typename T, typename U>
void c(T, U);

void c(auto, auto) {}

// D1: Clang OK, GCC error
template <typename T, typename U>
void d(T, U);

template <typename T>
void d(T, auto) {}

// E1: Clang error, GCC error
template <typename T>
void e(T, auto);

template <typename T>
void e(auto, T) {}

int main() {
    a(0);      // Clang OK, GCC error.
    b(0);      // Clang OK, GCC error.
    c(0, '0'); // Clang OK, GCC error.
    d(0, '0'); // Clang OK, GCC error.
    e(0, '0'); // Clang error, GCC error.
}
```

Curiously, if we make the function template a class member function template, both GCC and Clang accepts cases **A1** through **D1**, but both rejects the final case **E1** above:

```
// A2: OK
struct Sa {
    template <typename T>
    void a(T);
};

void Sa::a(auto) {}

// B2: OK
struct Sb {
    void b(auto);
};

template <typename T>
void Sb::b(T) {}

// C2: OK
struct Sc {
    template <typename T, typename U>
    void c(T, U);
};

void Sc::c(auto, auto) {}

// D2: OK
struct Sd {
    template <typename T, typename U>
    void d(T, U);
};

template <typename T>
void Sd::d(T, auto) {}

// E2: Error
struct Se {
   template <typename T>
   void e(T, auto);
};

template <typename T>
void Se::e(auto, T) {}
```

with the following error messages:

> **GCC**
>
> ```
> error: no declaration matches 'void Se::e(auto:7, T)'
>
> note: candidate is: 
>   'template<class T, class auto:6> void Se::e(T, auto:6)'
> ```
>
> **Clang**
>
> ```
> error: out-of-line definition of 'e' does not match 
> any declaration in 'Se'
> ```

Now, the *name* of a type template parameter is not required to be consistent over re-declaration (or a definition) of a function template, as just names a generic type placeholder.

GCC's error message is particularly interesting, hinting that invented type template parameters are treated as concrete types rather than generic type placeholders.

#### Question:

- Which of GCC and Clang are correct regarding cases **A1** through **D1** (rejecting and accepting, respectively)? Are GCC and Clang correct to reject case **E2** above? What standard passage (of the working draft) unambiguously supports them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This:

> ```
> template <typename T>
> void e(T, auto);
> ```

Translates to this:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
void e(T, U);
```

By contrast, this:

> ```
> template <typename T>
> void e(auto, T) {}
> ```

translates to:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
void e(U, T) {}
```

Remember that [abbreviated function template parameters are placed at the end of the template parameter list](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.fct#19). So those aren't declaring the same template, due to reversing the order of the template parameters. The first one declares one template, the second one declares and defines a *different* template.

You don't get a compile error just from this because the second definition is also a declaration. However, when you use a class member, out-of-member definitions are *not declarations*. Therefore, they must have a matching in-member declaration. Which they don't; hence the errors.

---

As for the others, the "functionally equivalent (but not equivalent)" text is a non-normative notation. The actual normative text that you quoted clearly states that these are "equivalent", not merely "functionally equivalent". And since the term "equivalent", per [[temp.over.link]/7](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.over.link#7), is used to match declarations and definitions, it seems to me that the standard states that the A through D cases are fine.

What's weird is that this non-normative text was [introduced by the same proposal that introduced the normative text](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1141r2.html). However, the proposal that it inherited the `ConceptName auto` syntax from [seems clear that it *means* "equivalent", not "functionally equivalent"](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/p0807r0.html).

So in terms of normative text, everything seems clear. But the presence of the non-normative contradiction suggests either an editorial problem or an actual defect in the spec.

---

While the standard itself is clear and normatively reasonable in terms of wording, it appears that this is not what the writers of the standard *intended*.

[P0717](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0717r1.pdf) introduced the concept of "functionally equivalent" as being distinct from "equivalent". And that proposal was accepted. However, P0717 was introduced early in the process of adopting the Concepts TS for C++20. In that proposal, it specifically spoke of terse template syntax, and EWG explicitly voted in favor of adopting "functionally equivalent" wording for it instead of the Concepts TS "equivalent" wording.

That is, P0717 makes it clear that the committee *intended* for users to be required to use consistent syntax.

However, terse template syntax from Concepts TS was removed from C++20 (or rather, never really added). Which meant that any "functionally equivalent" wording never made it in, since the feature never made it in.

Then P1141 happened, which added abbreviated template syntax, that covered much of the ground of the Concepts TS terse template syntax. But, despite one of the authors of P0717 being an author of P1141, apparently someone made a mistake in the wording and nobody caught it. This would explain why the non-normative text calls out the lack of true equivalence: because that was actually the committee's intent.

So it's very possible that this is a mistake in the normative text.

Comment: Ah, I see. Following this reasoning, would then **A1** through **D1** (and similarly, **A2** through **D2**) be well-formed, such that GCC is wrong in rejecting **A1** through **D1**?

Comment: @dfri: I didn't say that. I only said that case E *definitely does not match* and why. That is, they are not "equivalent" of either form.

Comment: Yes you're correct, sorry for jumping to further conclusion beyond your answer. My interpretation is that the two declarations in examples **A1** through **D1** declares the same equivalent function template and thus that GCC's current HEAD has a bug/not-yet-fully-compliant w.r.t. this feature.

Comment: @dfri: I've added some discussion about cases A through D.

Comment: Thanks, I agree with your discussion. Do you perhaps happen to know what would be a good place to discuss this possible spec wording problem? Would the [isocpp Std-Discussion mailing list](https://lists.isocpp.org/mailman/listinfo.cgi/std-discussion) be a plausible place to start?

Comment: @dfri: I'd say that you should file an issue on the [C++ draft GitHub](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft). At present, this would be considered an editorial issue, due to the inconsistency [between the normative and non-normative text](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/wiki/How-to-tell-if-an-issue-is-editorial). If they want to change the normative text instead, they may elevate it to a proper CWG issue.

Comment: That looks like the appropriate place to start (_"[...] Non-normative text is contained in code examples and notes [...] and does not have any bearing on the meaning of the standard. Changes to such wording can usually be done by the editor when requested."_), thanks!

Comment: This is definitely meant to be functionally equivalent but not equivalent, but the intent is clear enough that the normative text can probably be fixed editorially regardless. See the rationale in https://wg21.link/P0717R1, which reported an EWG poll of 15/14/13/2/3.

Comment: @T.C.: Noted and added to the answer.